# Universal Analytics tracking for embedded Flash content

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, google-analytics

We have a Flash (Flex) application embedded on a webpage. The webpage already has our Universal Analytics JavaScript code, and now we want to also track the application's events using Universal Analytics.

We can implement event tracking in the application directly using the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide). However, I'm wondering if that would mean that the stats coming from the application would be considered separate from what's coming from the Universal Analytics `ga` object on the page, i.e. not attributed to the same user/visitor.

Would it make sense to implement an approach where AS3 code would invoke methods of the page's `ga` JavaScript object instead?